# Is it possible to disable auto popping up of the terminal while running a code with code runner in VS Code?

Tags: terminal, vscode-code-runner

I want to run my program with code runner extension from Visual Studio Code and when I run the program it should run but the terminal shouldn't appear unless I explicitly open the terminal.

I need this because I take inputs from a file and write the outputs on another file. So, I don't need to see the terminal while doing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.